# How do i know a compiler isn't injecting malware into my program

Tags: python, security

I recently wrote my first application in python and it works quite well.
A bit later my anti-virus program flagged and uninstalled it as a trojan.

After a bit of research, I believe it is because I haven't signed my code but it made me think. Couldn't a compiler modify my Program by basically adding a piece of malware into your otherwise legit code? And how would I figure out if it does it?

This might be a really dumb question but I couldn't find any answers by googling and am new and trying to learn and understand. =

Comment: If you download the compiler from trusted sources, they might uses hashes/checksums to help you verify you're getting the authentic compiler.

Comment: In short: yes, a compiler just spits out a bunch of code which supposedly behaves like the code you put into it, but there’s really no such guarantee. Since a compiler may substantially change the structure of the code while keeping the same behavior, proving that input are output are equivalent isn’t necessarily easy.

Comment: The reason your antivirus flagged your program is likely just because you tripped one of its heuristics, which aren’t necessarily always spot on exactly.

Answer (score 5):

> Couldn't a compiler modify my Program by basically adding a piece of malware into your otherwise legit code. And how would I figure out if it does it?

Ken Thompson wrote a great article about this

- 1984, [Reflections on Trusting Trust,](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) Communications of the ACM

> To what extent should one trust a statement that a program is free of Trojan
> horses? Perhaps it is more important to trust the people who wrote the
> software.

He described how a trojan horse can be put into the C compiler and based on the fact that a new C compiler is compiled with the current C compiler ( chicken-egg)

- First, insert the trojan into C compiler code
- Compile it, now the new C compiler has the trojan that injects itself into every code it compiles.
- Rollback to the old C compiler code, and compile it with the new compiler.
- The C compiler source code doesn't have the trojan, but the compiler has it and carries it into every program it compiles even the future C compilers.

Well at some time this can be detected. The moral, however, is that

> The moral is obvious. You can't trust code that you did not totally create yourself. (Especially code from companies that employ people like me.) No amount of
> source-level verification or scrutiny will protect you
> from using untrusted code. In demonstrating the possibility of this kind of attack, I picked on the C compiler.
> I could have picked on any program-handling program
> such as an assembler, a loader, or even hardware microcode. As the level of program gets lower, these bugs
> will be harder and harder to detect. A well-installed
> microcode bug will be almost impossible to detect

This is a trust issue. Until now, you trusted to your the compiler, your antivirus program, and your OS. Now your compiler and your antivirus are fighting. Couldn't be it the case that your antivirus has been corrupted? Couldn't be the case that your operating system is corrupted?

The best action is to turn off the PC and do an external analysis of the system.

---

Wait, will you trust the external analyzer?

---

And, will you trust your hardware?

This is a serious issue unfortunately poisoned by Bloomberg.

- [Chinese Supply-Chain Attack on Computer System](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2021/02/chinese-supply-chain-attack-on-computer-systems.html)
- [The Register's arguments](https://www.theregister.com/2021/02/12/supermicro_bloomberg_spying/)

---

Note:  Need an example for outsourcing then see the SolarWinds attack.

Comment: Wait, do you trust your hardware? Some Chinese manufacturers have [created mainboards](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2021/02/chinese-supply-chain-attack-on-computer-systems.html) with an extra chip containing a backdoor.

Comment: @Thomas we talked about the Bloomberg article(s) in the chat of Cryptography.SE. The supply-chain attack is a serious issue and Bloomberg poisons the subject. None of the claims about the SuperMicro is proven and the second article also seems bogus. The best attack that I know is due to the NSA that modified the laptops during the order transmissions. [theregister](https://www.theregister.com/2021/02/12/supermicro_bloomberg_spying/)

Comment: Hm, I thought Schneier knew his stuff. To what extent should one trust an article? Perhaps it is more important to trust the people who wrote the article... ;)

Comment: @Thomas Schneier also says; `Independent from this article, I know that the DoD believes this threat is real and is giving away R&D funding for security solutions. So I have more than the Bloomberg reporting to go on.` The attack vector is large, the subject is serious, however, the way Bloomberg writes posing the subject.

Comment: @Thomas you might be interested in https://twitter.com/pwnallthethings/status/1360234953011851264 and Schneier is not a hardware person.

Answer (score -1):

I am working for Anti-malware company and I am really surpriser by your post.

1. Anti-malware programs do not "uninstall" malware. They remove file. Though they can do some cleanup, but it is not "uninstalling"
2. Your python code can not be "signed" as it should be .EXE file or some driver.
3. 99% is that you have faced "false positive" - some heuristic/Machine Learning detection that found that your code is *simmilar* to known malware.

Name of malware and name of antivirus product could help. You can address this problem to antivirus company support.

Comment: This answer seems to completely miss the point of the question and instead get hung up on semantics and tangential issues.